# I can't delete the folder's content from path

Tags: android, path, android-storage

I'm currently getting this path from my FileExplorer

```
val path = "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary:Download"
```

And I'm trying to delete the content of this location:

```
     val fileFolder = File(path)
     deleteFolderContent(fileFolder)

     private fun deleteFolderContent(fileFolder: File) {
        val files = fileFolder.listFiles()
        if (files.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            return
        } else {
            for (file in files) {
                file.delete()
            }
        }
    }
```

But `files` is always null and I can't delete the content. What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Update:

For obtain this "path" I did this:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_FOLDER_REQUEST_CODE)

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == SELECT_FOLDER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val uriTree = data?.data 
     }
}
```

Comment: You threat that content scheme as a file system path. That' what's wrong.

Comment: Which action did you use to obtain that uri/content scheme?

Comment: @blackapps I have updated the question with the method that I did to obtain it.

Comment: You obtained a SAF uri. You can try with. DocumentFile.deleteFile() or DocumentFile.deleteDirectory() whichever there is.

Comment: Further you will not delete the content but the directory itself only if it is empty...

Comment: Thanks @blackapps but I want to delete the content of my Download's Folder, not the folder Downloads

Comment: Well you know how to do that: list the content (as you did using the File class) and delete the content.

Comment: But files is always null and I can't delete the content.  @blackapps

Comment: ??? You cannot use the File class. I told you what to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can't access `content` directory as a `File` (even when `URI` points on local storage). check out `Provider`s and `ContentResolver`, [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics) you have some basics, for files there is special one: [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider). but for your case [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers) may fit for your needs best, with method:

```
context.contentResolver.delete(uriToDelete, null, null)
```